# Converting a plain ruby test of method that uses CSV and YAML data files into RSpec test

Tags: csv, rspec, yaml

I must convert a just plain ruby test I wrote some time ago, for a method called #mapper, to an RSpec test.

This method is very data driven, which required a lot of input and output data stored in a combination of CSV and YAML external data files.

Currently this is a ruby stand alone environment, but will soon be integrated in to a rails project.

Here is some pseudo code:

```
# current test algorithm
inputs = data_load :inputs
meta_maps = data_load :meta_maps
meta_maps.each do |meta_map_name, meta_map|
  outputs = data_load "outputs_#{meta_map_name}"        
  outputs.each do | output |
    next if output_data_not_available(output)
    test_name = output[:test_name]
    input = inputs[test_name]

    test test_name, output, mapper(input, meta_map)

  end
end
```

The `data_load` function loads a CSV or YAML file and returns it as a like named hash.

The `test` function calls the mapper function with the current `input` and compares what it returns with the current `output` and logs the result using the `test_name`.

The real issue is that I MUST use the external files (per specification - and they are not under my control)

I am new to RSpec but have basic understanding of it, but I have not used fixtures or factory type setups before and really need a way to integrate the CSV and YAML files into an RSpec test in the most "RSpec way" possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can "Read the Fine Manual" for all the ways you can set up data from within RSpec:

- https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/helper-methods
- https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/hooks
- https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-10/docs/example-groups

Since RSpec is layered on top of Ruby, you have access to all of Ruby's functionality to set up whatever data you need for your tests.

Comment: I have RTFM and none of what I have read seems to directly apply to this situation.  I was looking for some one with experience in this area to perhaps give some guidelines or suggestions.  More importantly, I was looking for approaches that are RSpec friendly.  IOW, I do not want to rubify the crap out of it.